# Why was this answer edited?

Tags: discussion, editing, moderation

Why was [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/76458/23541) edited?

[image]

The link has worked, and was clickable.

Comment: Why have you deleted your answer now?  It seems like a reasonable answer, the age of the movie you reference is in the right ballpark for being the best answer.

Answer (score 10):

The link was linking specifically to the *mobile* site version of IMDb (using the prepended `m.`). This is problematic since those sites are optimized for mobile devices and thus tend to look improperly on desktop devices. This usually results from people writing answers with links on mobile devices and can thus happen now and then.

However, this is easy to fix, since the *normal adress of the site shows the mobile site on mobile devices anyway* and the desktop site on desktop devices. So just **removing the `m.` is an easy fix to make the link show properly for *all* users** and thus doesn't force users to a specific version of the site possibly not optimized for their devices.

This is a problem [occuring occasionally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243891/162011) across [the network](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/15896) and something that's unfortunately [not fixable automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260843/162011) yet. But fortunately we have avid users trying to help improve the site and its users' experience with helpful edits.

Comment: (Gotta wonder why on earth these sites *have* a `m.` version at all, if the normal address redirects to the mobile site on mobile devices anyway.)

Comment: True. I'd ascribe that to technical problems. The redirect has to go *somewhere else*, I guess. And once it went there, there's no way to know how you *got* there from the plain URL alone anymore. But I'm no web developer either.

Comment: You'd think that it could be smart enough to do the opposite... clicking a mobile link from a system identified as a regular computer would take you to the full site rather than the mobile site.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the only way the normal site can redirect to the mobile site is if there _is_ a mobile site to redirect to. The desktop version detects that your browser is a mobile user-agent and sends a redirect that loads the `m.imdb.com` version of the same page, but it's not doing anything a human couldn't have done manually -- just doing it automatically.